# Named pipe faster than normal pipe in bash?

Tags: bash, performance, named-pipes

I'm currently writing a bash script in which I'm using a lot of named pipes. I thought that this might create a bit of overhead as compared to using pipes directly, but I decided that I'm okay with that, I just wanted to get some stats to find out how much exactly I'm dealing with. I therefore ran these two commands 50 times each, writing down the times to then average:

```
time seq 1000000 | sort | head;
time seq 1000000 | cat >a | cat a | sort | head; #a was created with mkfifo
```

This is not the actual way I'll be using named pipes

To write down the times, I used this command:

```
for i in `seq 50`; do { time seq 1000000 | sort | head; } 2>&1 | grep real | cut -c8-12 >> normal_pipe; done
```

To my astonishment, I discovered these results:

Normal pipe:
Average: 1.712 sec
stddev: 0.0157 sec

Unnamed pipe:
Average: 1.644 sec
stddev: 0.0339 sec

My questions are now:

- Why is the named pipe faster?
- Is my benchmarking setup flawed?
- Or is the difference probably just due to other processes running in the background?

I'm guessing that, since `sort` can only start working once it has all the input (right?), this is about how quickly the pipe spits out the EOF...

Comment: `seq 100 | cat > a | cat a | sort` can be written as `seq 100 > a & sort a`.

Comment: Two sigma, nothing special.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ran the same tests a few times on my machine and the results showed little difference between the two styles of piping.  My hunch is a difference of .068 seconds is nothing special and is just due to background tasks, like you said.